# Lua 4.0 random number generator

Tags: random, lua, prng

I don't have access to random() in Lua 4.0 (DON'T ASK), so I need to roll my own random number generator. Or rather I have to roll *another* one since the one I implemented several years ago is failing me now. I.e. I am noticing repeating values which is bad.

Any suggestions or examples written in Lua that I can use? FYI here's the one I've been using up until now:

```
seedobja = 1103515245
seedobjc = 12345
seedobjm = 4294967295 --0x100000000

function srandom(seedobj, fVal1, fVal2)
    seedobj[1] = mod(seedobj[1] * seedobja + seedobjc, seedobjm)
    local temp_rand = seedobj[1] / (seedobjm - 1)
    if (fVal2) then
        return floor(fVal1 + 0.5 + temp_rand * (fVal2 - fVal1))
    elseif (fVal1) then
        return floor(temp_rand * fVal1) + 1
    else
        return temp_rand
    end
end
```

[edit]

Later edit deleted.

Comment: If you have access to os.clock() this should provide you with a suitable seed.

Comment: so I have to ask anyway, why isn't `math.random` available?

Comment: It's for a video game, and the developers decided to replace/override random() with a function that gets a new seed every time the game starts. I need a script that I can rely on producing the same results with the same seed every time the script is run. Getting the seed from the clock is not going to help me.

Comment: Has anyone rewritten the Marsenne twister script in Lua?

Comment: There's a [lrandom](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lrandom) C module provided by lhf that uses  Mersenne Twister.

Comment: I can't install C modules unfortunately.

Comment: You can use any hash function as good pseudo random number generator if you could find one written in Lua.

Comment: What are your requirements for the random number generator? Must it have some guaranteed statistical properties or will a quick and dirty solution be enough? For which application/problem domain will the generator be used?

Comment: The generator is being used to plot 3D mathematical points, so there should not be any duplicates. I'm not sure what other properties would be useful.

Comment: I updated the question. Could someone test the second bit of code for me?

Comment: Since you are using a Linear Congruential Generator algorithm, be prepared to cope with the problem identified by Marsaglia in this class of generators when used to get random points in multidimensional spaces. The problem is explained easily [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/lcg_planes.shtml) in the context of Java. In short, the generated points are not uniformly distributed in the 3D space, but tend to clump together in parallel planes. I don't know if this may adversely affect your use case, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: I'm OK with the banding or whatever you want to call it. The problem I'm experiencing is WRT the numbers starting to repeat themselves after several thousand executions. I want all UNIQUE values over a longer period. Say, over 100000 executions at least.

Comment: FYI, I found some Lua scripts [here](http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3424&start=20), but they were written in a convoluted way for Lua 5.0. I've tried converting them but haven't had luck getting them to work in Lua 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another attempt (always Lua 5.1 code), using an adaptation from C of a subtractive generator by Knuth (not linear congruential then). According to Knuth it should work with FP arithmetic (even single precision).

```
local mod = math.fmod
local floor = math.floor
local abs = math.abs

local B =  4000000

-- rough adaptation of Knuth float generator
function srandom( seedobj, fVal1, fVal2 )
    local ma = seedobj.ma
    local seed = seedobj.seed
    local mj, mk
    if seed < 0 or not ma then
        ma = {}
        seedobj.ma = ma
        mj = abs( 1618033 - abs( seed ) )
        mj = mod( mj, B )
        ma[55] = mj
        mk = 1
        for i = 1, 54 do
            local ii = mod( 21 * i,  55 )
            ma[ii] = mk
            mk = mj - mk
            if mk < 0 then mk = mk + B end
            mj = ma[ii]
        end
        for k = 1, 4 do
            for i = 1, 55 do
                ma[i] = ma[i] - ma[ 1 + mod( i + 30,  55) ]
                if ma[i] < 0 then ma[i] = ma[i] + B end
            end
        end
        seedobj.inext = 0
        seedobj.inextp = 31
        seedobj.seed = 1
    end -- if
    local inext = seedobj.inext
    local inextp = seedobj.inextp
    inext = inext + 1
    if inext == 56 then inext = 1 end
    seedobj.inext = inext
    inextp = inextp + 1
    if inextp == 56 then inextp = 1 end
    seedobj.inextp = inextp
    mj = ma[ inext ] - ma[ inextp ]
    if mj < 0 then mj = mj + B end
    ma[ inext ] = mj
    local temp_rand = mj / B
    if fVal2 then
        return floor( fVal1 + 0.5 + temp_rand * ( fVal2 - fVal1 ) )
    elseif fVal1 then
        return floor( temp_rand * fVal1 ) + 1
    else
        return temp_rand
    end
end

-- test

-- Note: seedobj must be a table with a field named `seed`;
-- this field must be negative; after the first number has
-- been generated, the seedobj table will be populated with
-- additional state needed to generate numbers; changing its
-- `seed` field to a negative number will reinitialize the
-- generator and start a new pseudorandom sequence.
local seedobj = { seed = -232343 }
for i = 1, 100 do
    print( srandom( seedobj, 100, 1000 ) )
end
```

Comment: This one seems to work better. There are a few duplicate values here and there, but they are sporadic. After 10000 iterations there were only 12 duplicates, compared to several hundred or thousand with the previous attempts. I'll have to rewrite all my other scripts to the new format of `seedobj` though. I'll do a little more testing before I accept this answer.

Comment: @posfan12 Sorry but maybe I didn't understand. Are you looking for a generator that doesn't repeat *any* number before ending its period? If this is the case probably your requirements are a bit too much. Pseudorandom generators such as these don't make any attempt at *not* repeating numbers, because the sequence must resemble an *actual random sequence* (say the outcome of rolling a die). If you put the additional constraint that any already seen number cannot be seen again before the entire sequence repeats, you are skewing the randomness of the sequence and making it more predictable.

Comment: @posfan12 Of course there are application where you do want to avoid any repetitions, and there are techniques to achieve that, but are you sure you need that. Avoiding repetitions doesn't increase the randomness of the sequence, if this is what you're after, it's exactly the contrary.

Comment: A handful of duplicates is OK, as long as they are not all in a row. I am using the script to plot 3D points of video game objects, so if all three coordinates repeat and cause the objects to overlap it can cause problems in the game.

Comment: The LCG function was producing visible artifacts, so I went with this one after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have not Lua 4.0 installed and never worked with it, thus the following code may need some tweaks.

This is something that works on Lua 5.1. It is a rough adaptation of an implementation of the Park and Miller generator (written in C, using 32 bit ints). I tried to come closer to the 4.0 syntax (that I guessed from your snippet). Test it and see if its period suits your needs. The original version has a period of about `2e9`, but converting to float arithmetic may have broken something (these generators are delicate things).

```
local mod = math.fmod
local floor = math.floor

local B = 2^31
-- rough adaptation of Park-Miller generator
function srandom( seedobj, fVal1, fVal2 )
    local seed = seedobj[1]
    local k = mod( floor( seed / 127773 ), B )
    seed = mod( 16807 * ( seed - mod( k * 127773, B ) ), B )
    seed = seed - mod( 2836 * k, B )
    if seed < 0 then seed = mod( seed + B - 1, B ) end
    seedobj[1] = seed
    local temp_rand = seed / ( B - 1 )
    if fVal2 then
        return floor( fVal1 + 0.5 + temp_rand * ( fVal2 - fVal1 ) )
    elseif fVal1 then
        return floor( temp_rand * fVal1 ) + 1
    else
        return temp_rand
    end
end

-- test
local seedobj = { 2 }   -- first element is the seed and must not be 0
for i = 1, 100 do
    print( srandom( seedobj, 100, 1000 ) )
end
```

Comment: I have the same problem with your code. The numbers start repeating themselves. In this case they start repeating at about the 8500 iteration, which is an improvement but is still bad. On the discussion board for the game someone suggested to me that the version of Lua included with it was compiled to use single-precision floating-points instead of double. I don't know what to do if this is the case.

Comment: @posfan12 If Lua number is single precision FP then that may be well the cause of `srandom` too short a period, since single precision floats have only 23 (IIRC) bits of significand, which are too few to perform 32-bit integer calculations without roundoff. There are algorithms which are especially designed to work with 16-bit integers, but I have none at hand. Adapting one of those may work.

Comment: @posfan12 To test whether your numbers are single precision execute this line `print(2^25)`. Double precision can handle it with no problem and print `33554432`. If you get a different result you probably have single precision numbers.

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: Does `print(2^1000)` print something similar to `1.0715086071863e+301`?

Comment: I get 1.071508607186267e+301.

Comment: @posfan12 It seems you have double-precision arithmetic. Anyway I posted another answer with a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution [here](http://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3424):

```
function mul16(a, b)
    local a_lo, b_lo = mod(a, 2^8), mod(b, 2^8)
    local a_hi, b_hi = a - a_lo, b - b_lo
    return mod(a_lo * b_lo + mod(a_lo * b_hi, 2^16) + mod(a_hi * b_lo, 2^16) + mod(a_hi * b_hi, 2^16), 2^16)
end

function lcg(s, r)
    local temp = {}
    function temp:random(a, b)
        local y = mod(mul16(self.a, self.x) + self.c, self.m)
        self.x = y
        if not a then
            return y / 65536
        elseif not b then
            if a == 0 then
                return y
            else
                return 1 + mod(y, a)
            end
        else
            return a + mod(y, b - a + 1)
        end
    end
    function temp:randomseed(s)
        if not s then
            s = seed()
        end
        self.x = mod(s, 2147483648)
    end
    -- 'Numerical Recipes' parameters
    temp.a = 26125
    temp.c = 62303
    temp.m = 65536
    temp:randomseed(s)
    return temp
end

local R = lcg(0974)
local rand_table = {}
for i = 1, 10000 do
    local new_value = R:random()
    rand_table[i] = new_value
    if (i > 1) then
        for j = 1, i - 1 do
            local old_value = rand_table[j]
            if (new_value == old_value) then
                print("\ti = " .. i .. "\n\tj = " .. j .. "\n\tnew_value = " .. new_value .. "\n\told_value = " .. old_value)
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I don't know about the statistical properties, but the function is not returning duplicate values even after many thousands of iterations. Thanks for everyone's help regardless!

Comment: Darn. The "planes" produced by the LCG function and described elsewhere in this thread are very apparent. I can't use this function.