# Lua newbie: Alternate (Knuth) pseudo-random function performance?

Tags: performance, random, lua

I'm developing a roguelike in Lua for iOS and OSX. Pretty new to Lua and discovered to my dismay how *nonrandom* **math.random** is on my platform. I already had already setup my calls for random numbers set up through a function:

```
function rollD(max)
   return math.random(max)
end
```

So I found a fantastic answer in response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689186/lua-4-0-random-number-generator) which turns out I think will solve my problem (it's pretty critical for a roguelike that the game be different each time) But in order to make the following tweaked function:

```
function rollD(max)
    return srandom(seedobj,1,max)
end
```

work, I had to make:

```
local seedobj = { seed = -232343 }
```

from Donati's Knuth adaptation not be local anymore, and then actually modified it to use (os.time()*-1). This actually works perfectly so far and my (very rudimentary) roguelike is rolling up random bad guys and dungeons just like I want it to. But I worry when things work right...

With a high number of calls to **srandom** (probably upwards of a thousand calls per level) am I going to take some kind of performance hit by having **seedobj** be global? I would like to think that, because it's nested in the table, that seed is a reference and that I'm worrying for nothing. But otherwise: is there a way I should modify this function so I can call it more efficiently?

Comment: The right way of crediting a person is to accept their answers and/or upvote their questions/answers (this latter can be done when you reach at least 15 rep points). Thanking a person in the text of a question/answer is not acceptable (it adds useless clutter in the Q/A). Sometimes a comment can be used (especially if you want to underline ***why*** an answer was useful), but don't abuse them for simple "thanks" (or say "thanks" and remove the comment after a couple of days). So please edit your question to remove the praises (I appreciate them, but they don't belong there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a global variable in Lua is like accessing a table field. If `seedobj` is global the following code:

```
function rollD(max)
    return srandom(seedobj,1,max)
end
```

in Lua 5.2 is equivalent to:

```
function rollD(max)
    return srandom(_ENV.seedobj,1,max)
end
```

or in Lua 5.1 is (roughly) equivalent to

```
function rollD(max)
    return srandom(_G.seedobj,1,max)
end
```

Where [`_ENV`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2) is the variable holding the current environment table and [`_G`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.1) is the variable holding the global table.

Therefore whenever you call `rollD` you incur a small performance penalty for that indirect access, compared to a local variable. In general this penalty is significant or not depending on the complexity of the other operations performed when you call `rollD`.

In your specific case that penalty is unlikely to be noticeable, since the `srandom` implementation already performs much more intensive computations (among which some table accesses as well).