# Lua vs PHP Random Numbers

Tags: php, encryption, random, lua

I have a lua script that encrypts a string and sends it via http to a PHP script. Problem is, the encryption process uses Lua's `math.randomseed` and `math.random`. When trying to decrypt the string in PHP, `mt_srand` and `mt_rand` produce different numbers than Lua did.

How can I get php to generate numbers like Lua?

-- Edit

Ok, so in my (very simple) encryption I'm using a key to generate a seed. That seed lets me get back the same "random number" each time.

So if my key produces a seed of say, 80 and I use this in Lua...

```
math.randomseed(80)
local randomNumber = math.random(1, 20)
// randomNumber = 3
```

When trying to decrypt in PHP, I'll use the same seed but I get a different output.

```
mt_srand(80);
$randomNumber = mt_rand(1, 20);
// $randomNumber = 10
```

I need to figure out a way to get back the same number so that I'm able to decrypt the string.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you have a problem with random number generators generating different numbers?

Comment: You need to give us more detail on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks a bit weird. Pseudo-random generators shouldn't generate the same number twice in a row. It seems like you're looking for a hash/salt instead, though the appropriate way to do this would be using (a)symmetric keys to encrypt and decrypt in both ends.

Comment: They're not executed in a sequence, they're executed only once to get the first "random number". Basically, it's used as an offset to change the characters ordinal number. Nothing special, just a very, very simple encryption.

Comment: @user1960364 Oh I see. The [manpage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) says: "PHP 5.2.1 The Mersenne Twister implementation in PHP now uses a new seeding algorithm by Richard Wagner. Identical seeds no longer produce the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe to rely upon it nonetheless."

Comment: Well, I am running 5.2.17 and I'm getting the same sequence of numbers every time I load the page with a seed of 80. "10, 7, 14, 11, 6, 17". Anyway, the problem is that it generates a different number than Lua, I need a way to generate the same number but looking at Lua's source, I can't figure out how. I imagine I'd have to write my own random function in PHP to replicate Lua, if possible.. :-/ http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lmathlib.c.html#math_random

Comment: Weird, though the manual states that the sequences are no longer the same it did in fact generate the same sequences running PHP 5.5 as well. Either way, as you've already noticed, these pseudo-random number generators' implementations seem to differ so it is unlikely to get the same result. Those generators usually rely on some source of pseudo-randomness provided by the OS, hence I'm not really sure how to implement an algorithm to generate the same (random?) number based on a seed, sorry.

Comment: The built-in `math.random` in Lua is simply a wrapper around the underlying C runtime's `rand()`. ANSI C specifies that `rand()` exist, but does not require that it have any particular implementation. Most ANSI C compilers I've looked at closely, however, implement the same generator provided as an example in the standard, which is a particular linear congruential generator chosen with some care to avoid most of the pitfalls with a LCRNG and give as long a sequence as possible in 32-bit integers. Since Lua depends on `rand()`, it cannot be counted on to reproduce a sequence for a seed value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689186/lua-4-0-random-number-generator for some code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel by replicating an existing random function from either Lua or PHP for the opposite language. I found that using the approach on the following link to be much easier. Simply ported the code to Lua and all is well. Obviously, it's not going to fit everyones case, but for how I'm using it, it's perfect and simple.
http://www.sitepoint.com/php-random-number-generator/

```
class Random {

    // random seed
    private static $RSeed = 0;

    // set seed
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }

    // generate random number
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }

}
```

Only thing I changed was the default seed, and removed the line using mt_rand()

Then in Lua I created the following code:

```
local mySeed = 0;

function setSeed(s)
    mySeed = math.abs(tonumber(s)) % 9999999 + 1;
    myRand();
end

function myRand(min, max)
    min = min or 0;
    max = max or 9999999;
    mySeed = (mySeed * 125) % 2796203;
    return mySeed % (max - min + 1) + min;
end
```

Comment: There is a standard litany of warnings about rolling your own crypto which I assume you will discover if you depend on this for anything beyond a simple obfuscation. The technique of implementing the same generator in your own code in both (all) platforms is sound. As long as this isn't protecting anything even as valuable as your diary, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a random-number-generator which use the same algorithm on php and lua.

Either you find an random-number-generator for Lua and one for PHP which has the same implementation, or you must programm your own one. Moreover, using of system intern generators are also bad, because they can change everytime, and then your script also no longer works.