# PRNGs and seed values

Tags: random, lua

I am using the following PRNG in a Lua script:

```
inputseed = {763261}
seedobja = 1103515.245
seedobjc = 12345
seedobjm = 4294967.295 --0x100000000

function srandom(seedobj, fVal1, fVal2)
    seedobj[1] = mod(seedobj[1] * seedobja + seedobjc, seedobjm)
    local temp_rand = seedobj[1] / (seedobjm - 1)
    if (fVal2) then
        return floor(fVal1 + 0.5 + temp_rand * (fVal2 - fVal1))
    elseif (fVal1) then
        return floor(temp_rand * fVal1) + 1
    else
        return temp_rand
    end
end

-- the returned value should be a float between 0 and 1
local randomvalue_a = srandom(inputseed)
-- the returned value should be an integer between 10 and 20
local randomvalue_b = srandom(inputseed, 10, 20)
```

My question is, do similar seed values produce similar results when run through a PRNG like this?

I mean, the numbers 3 and 5 are close to each other compared to a large number like 3001. Are the first two numbers likely to produce similar pseudo random values?

Thanks.

Comment: That generator doesn't look right to me.  It seems to be based on an integer LCG, but incorrectly adapted to floating-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is unrelated to question.

[Remember, Google loves us all.](https://www.google.ru/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=rng%20x%20%3D%20mod(x%20*a%20%2B%20b,%20c)&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=SY6CV-_KE6Xt6ASA-6r4CA)

This is linear congruental generator, well with additional whistle at the third line of your function definition.

If we look the formulas on line 2 and 3,you'll see that `x *a + b` and `x/(c-1)` are linear operations which have exactly your property, however at the line 2 there's also `mod(x,c)` operation which is actually periodically-linear with period c.
So, it is linearly periodic. That is except for a few points, its linear.

If you actually perform a straightforward test of the algorithm. (e.g. [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3Dmod(%20x*%201103515.245%2B12345%20,%204294967.295%20)%2F(%204294967.295%20-%201)%20from%200%20to%2020)), you'll see that for parameter given the period is about 3 or 4.

That is for values like 3  and 3.1 the results are close, but also are results for 3 and 6.87.

---

This high period btw, signifies that your generator is incorrect. Since you should be feeding the generator outputs to itself, you want it not to be linear at the span of outputs (its period must be significantly less than 1 for outputs in the range of (0,1)).

For this to happen, denominator must be lower than numerator in mod function. In your case, the `seedobjc` and `seedobjm` must be swapped.

Comment: Also, as @sh1 noted, the generator is incorrect, if fed its own output, it monotonously converges to a specific value by tenth step.

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do. (Also, I added a few lines of code to the bottom of the example to show how I am using the function.)

Comment: Is this function better?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18725427/330663 I totally forgot I started that topic.

Comment: Sorry for late response, as I said you need to swap values of `seedobjc` and `seedobjm`, so that `seedobjc=4294967.295` and `seedobjm=12345`.

Comment: And if `-- integer between 10 and 20` includes 10 and 20, I'd say the corresponding line should be `return floor(fVal1-0.5 + temp_rand * (fVal2+ 1  - fVal1))`

Comment: I'm unable to review the linked code but assuming it is without a typo, Knuth  developed that generator exactly as a replacement for LCG if I remember right, so it is probably not worse than this one.

Answer (score 1):

For most PRNGs similar seeds are extremely unlikely to produce similar results, and if you do need multiple seeds then adjacent integers are an ideal choice because it's easy to prove that they're all distinct and distributing those seeds appropriately is the responsibility of the PRNG designer (though it is possible for them to have done their job badly).

For that specific generator, you should probably just walk through the arithmetic and see what you get.  If it works correctly you should see that seeds 3 and 5 diverge just as quickly as 3 and 3001.